# How to vertically align text inside div without using inline-height

Tags: css, webforms, text-alignment

In the following example i am trying to align the text in middle vertically & horizontally.

For some reason it doesn't come up correctly i tried few example also

http://jsfiddle.net/kayen/JBnbG/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do with your CSS & get the result: http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/AMcnZ/31/

Remove `height` from `.boxcaption`.

```
.boxcaption{
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    background: #000;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center; /*Add this*/
    padding:5px 0 0 0; /*Add this*/
    opacity: .6;
    /* For IE 5-7 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60);
    /* For IE 8 */
    -MS-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60)";
}
```

Comment: Yes because there is a fixed height given to box caption.

Comment: So how can i get around this issue

Comment: I think better solution is to remove the height & let it grow with image Title, I will mark your answer correct as similar solution has been given by other user but you where the first one to do it this way. Appreciate everybody help.

Answer (score 2):

you can add to your **css**

```
text-align: center;
line-height: 30px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JBnbG/4/

Comment: I had mentioned in question itself without using inline-height, I tried this approach but it has a problem if the title is large then it will not show up due to inline-heigh:30px;

Answer (score 1):

demo http://jsfiddle.net/AMcnZ/22/

2nd demo http://jsfiddle.net/AMcnZ/32/

```
.boxcaption{
        float: left;
        position: absolute;
        background: #000;
        height: 25px;
        width: 100%;
        opacity: .6;
        padding-top:3px;
       text-align:center;
        /* For IE 5-7 */
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60);
        /* For IE 8 */
        -MS-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60)";
         }
```

Comment: see what happens if i add large title http://jsfiddle.net/AMcnZ/27/. It doesn't wrap the text

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker : if title is large and image width is small how come you able to fix in that, option is you have to change the font-size which is not good option

Comment: Title wont be very large but at-least it should be able to adjust two line at least.

Comment: you can see this approach has design problem even if i add small font size http://jsfiddle.net/AMcnZ/33/.. I want to do it with out adding padding..